# how to get update records which is newly inserted only in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to move data from old sql db to new sql db which are having same tables. but new table is having 100(assume) records and old db is having 1000 records. i inserted all records in new db but i got diffetent id's because this id is having identity in new db.

now my concern is how can i update new identity value for the foreigh key columns. 
the foreign key column is having duplicate in new db. i have to update foreign key column only for newly inserted records.

Comment: for example     id,childpartid, parentpartid(1,1,1    2, 2,1     3,3,2   4, 4,1) like this in old db and in new db   id,partid, parentpartid(1,2,1     2.2,2     3,3,2    5,1) allready available in new db. i have to insert old db vaues in new db with new identity and have to update those partid's in new db.

Answer (score 0):

go with [`IDENTITY INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

using this command you are allowed to insert values into an identity field instead of having SQL Server automatically filling the field.

Comment: its not about the identity insert ...the inserted values from old to new db will get new id's because of identity property.....so i have to update the foreign key columns with the latest id's...? is there any way for this?

Comment: the requirement is to drop old ids? if you copy the old ids you don't need to cascade update all the related columns.